# Referencing information within arrays stored with an ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nativescript

Currently I am pulling information from two JSON files stored online. My goal is to display the information stored within these files in my app, using one for content and the other for attributes that can apply to the content, like background and font color.

My main issue is this:

I am trying to fill an ObservableArray with other arrays, and then reference the information stored within each of those within the XML file. A fairly simple idea, yes?

**Content JSON**

```
{
"content": [
  {
    "description": "If youâ€™ve been dreaming about owning a customizable smartwatch, the modular watch that London-based Blocks promised is now available ...",
    "image": "https:\/\/cdn3.vox-cdn.com\/thumbor\/mOV6mjP_AI50YsQDbQ81444XEB4=\/0x21:2520x1701\/1310x873\/cdn0.vox-cdn.com\/uploads\/chorus_image\/image\/49811865\/hero-bg_2x.0.0.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467036570",
    "title": "The Blocks modular smartwatch can now be pre-ordered",
    "type": "04",
    "url": "http:\/\/www.theverge.com\/circuitbreaker\/2016\/6\/9\/11894152\/blocks-modular-smartwatch-pre-order"
  },
  {
    "description": "At Lenovo TechWorld, we got a glimpse at the Moto Z's developer mod kit and how it can be used to make wacky and weird slip-on attachments.",
    "image": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/A0YFmMEjXP0/mqdefault.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467032545",
    "title": "Lenovo's Experimental Moto Mods",
    "feedid": "03",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0YFmMEjXP0"
  },
  {
    "description": "",
    "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CkmZk8QXIAEKnTF.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467035885",
    "title": "The US just approved six airlines to begin flying to Cuba",
    "feedid": "02",
    "url": "http://www.theverge.com/2016/6/10/11903034/us-cuba-airlines-american-southwest-frontier-jetblue"
  },
  {
    "description": "'Texts from Hillary' photo raised questions about Clinton email habits at State Department",
    "image": "https://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/COJRCv7KVVwj3uO5qt1XHZ5F02Y=/0x82:3010x2089/1280x854/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49821307/AP_16147060028688.0.0.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467036728",
    "title": "The photo went viral enough to catch the eye of the State Department.",
    "feedid": "01",
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/verge/posts/1116679778368364"
  },
  {
    "description": "One of the benefits of being (somewhat) bilingual is you get double the internet content. I feel very blessed to be able to enjoy both American internet full of...",
    "image": "https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gM8KeNQUzto6fmdot7wfA_q9jSs=/0x0:3000x2000/1310x873/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49820235/GettyImages-499350590.0.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467036669",
    "title": "If you drop an ant from the top of the Empire State Building, will it die?",
    "feedid": "04",
    "url": "http://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/6/10/11894028/ant-dropped-from-empire-state-building-science-experiment"
  },
  {
    "description": "Tesla has denied that its cars suffer from suspension defects, suggesting that comments from the US National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTSA) have been misinterpreted.",
    "image": "https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/IAh-NZAZzH_AwdO2ubVMKlZkB2Y=/187x0:2212x1350/1310x873/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49819011/model-s-photo-gallery-06.0.0.jpg",
    "created_utc": "1467042890",
    "title": "Tesla denies Model S suspension defects, chides journalist in blog post",
    "feedid": "04",
    "url": "http://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/6/9/11894152/blocks-modular-smartwatch-pre-order"
  }
]
}
```

**Sources and Attributes JSON**

```
{
  "sources": [
    {
      "category":"news",
      "subject":"technology",
      "adsenabled":true,
      "bannerimgsrc":"https://www.camplaurel.com/images/pagegraphics/home/l-header-bg.jpg",
      "rowbgimgsrc":"https://www.camplaurel.com/images/pagegraphics/home/l-header-bg.jpg",
      "titlebgcolor":"#ffffff",
      "row2ndcolor":"#000000",
      "rowtxtcolor":"#e22805",
      "rowbgcolor":"#ffffff",
      "iconsrc": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/615501837341466624/I4jVBBp-.jpg",
      "id": 1,
      "shortname": "verge",
      "name": "The Verge"
    },
    {
      "category":"news",
      "subject":"leisure",
      "adsenabled":true,
      "bannerimgsrc":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/275686563/1433249898/1500x500",
      "rowbgimgsrc":"null",
      "titlebgcolor":"#ece4d1",
      "row2ndcolor":"#9b4e34",
      "rowtxtcolor":"#6b2e1e",
      "rowbgcolor":"#ece4d1",
      "iconsrc": "https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b13830f5a9baecd3d83ef5cae4d5107d25cdbfbe/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3732313033382f313732383830352f35336532613364382d363262352d313165332d383964312d3934376632373062646430332e706e67",
      "id": 1,
      "shortname": "Laurel South",
      "name": "Camp Laurel South, Mains Premier Sleep Over Camp"
    }
  ]
,
  "feeds": [
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "iconsrc": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/1024/facebook-icon.png",
      "id": 1,
      "notistat": "Sound and Text",
      "sourceid":1,
      "title": "The Verge Facebook"
    },
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "iconsrc": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/1024/facebook-icon.png",
      "id": 2,
      "notistat": "Sound and Text",
      "sourceid":1,
      "title": "The Verge Twitter"
    },
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "iconsrc": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/1024/facebook-icon.png",
      "id": 3,
      "notistat": "Sound and Text",
      "sourceid": 1,
      "title": "The Verge Youtube"
    },
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "iconsrc": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/1024/facebook-icon.png",
      "id": 4,
      "notistat": "Sound and Text",
      "sourceid": 1,
      "title": "The Verge RSS"
    }
  ]
}
```

My JavaScript file uses a variable listed as bindingContext as the bindingContext of the page. myArray is a part of the bindingContext, and is being pushed into by my JSON mapping and loading functions, at least in theory.

```
var Observable = require('data/observable').Observable;
var ObservableArray = require('data/observable-array').ObservableArray;
var http = require("http");
var moment = require('moment');
var frameModule = require('ui/frame');
var bindingContext = new Observable({
  title: "Loading...",
  myArray: new ObservableArray()
});


function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = bindingContext;

    loadSources();
    loadFeeds();
    loadContent();
}

function loadContent() {
  var content = [];
    http.getJSON("http://www.doesntmatter.com/jsoncontent.php")
    .then(function (r) {
        bindingContext.title = 'Notifications Up to Date';

         r.content.map( function(item) {
             item.friendlyTime = moment(item.created_utc * 1000).fromNow();
             content.push(item);

         });
         bindingContext.myArray.push(content);
         console.log("content loaded.");
    });
}

function loadSources() {
  var mysources = [];
    http.getJSON("http://www.secrets.com/jsonsource.php")
    .then(function (r) {
         r.sources.map( function(item) {
           mysources.push(item);
           console.log(item.name);
         });
    });
    bindingContext.myArray.push(mysources);
    console.log("sources loaded!");
    };
}
//LoadSources should add all listed Sources into an array of sources, which is then pushed into the larger "myArray" which allows coloration and other css items to be determined for each object within an array

function loadFeeds() {
  var myfeeds = [];
    http.getJSON("http://www.shhhhhhhh.com/jsonsource.php")
    .then(function (r) {
         r.feeds.map( function(item) {
             myfeeds.push(item);
         });
         bindingContext.myArray.push(myfeeds);
         console.log("feeds loaded.");
    });
}
//LoadFeeds should add all listed feeds into an array of feeds, which is also loaded into "myArray", which can then be drawn from to create individual color schemes

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

The part I am having a lot of trouble with is correctly referencing the array, subarrays, and contents of each within both the JavaScript file and the XML file due to a somewhat rusty knowledge of both languages.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">

<Page.actionBar>
  <ActionBar title="Notify">
  </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>

<ListView items="{{ myArray }}" itemTap="itemTap" loadMoreItems="loadMoreItems" class="containter">
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout rows="21,*,*" columns="90,*" width="*" height="*" >
     <!-- <Image row="0" col="0" colSpan="1" rowspan="3" src="{{ getItem[2].image }}" />  -->
    <!-- <Label row="0" col="1" colSpan="1" class="time" text="{{  friendlyTime  }}" textAlignment="right" /> -->
    <!-- <Label row="1" col="1" colSpan="1" class="title" text="{{ content.title }}" margin="1" textWrap="true" /> -->
    <!-- <Label row="2" col="1" colSpan="1" class="description" text="{{ description }}" textWrap="true" backgroundColor="{{ this is where I would want to reference the contents of the subarrays}}" /> -->
    </GridLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Page>
```

Again, just to reiterate: I have an ObservableArray which is part of the bindingContext of the page. This is being filled with other arrays, which are each filled with information I want to apply to my XML file. How can I reference this information using the correct syntax for both JavaScript and XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually need to rethink your design.  ;-)

First issue that occurred to me is that myArray[0] can end up being **content**, **sources** or **feeds**.   Just because you ran the code:

```
loadSources();
loadFeeds();
loadContent();
```

In a synchronous fashion, does not guarentee the result order; each one of those loads the file from a ASYNC source (i.e. in this case http); depending on which one of those ASYNC sources actually responds with its data first, it is which one will get put into your MyArray first.  ;-)

---

Your second issue is that 
`<ListView items="{{ myArray }}"`

Will only create three of your GridLayout templates; because their are only three myArray items (i.e the content, feeds, source) based on your data; I'm pretty sure you aren't just wanting to show three line items.

---

Now the question becomes do you need each item to link to a source to a feed, or do you just want to combine all three types and display each type of line item differently based on which type it it.

Comment: The sources and feeds will be applied to the content based on where it comes from, thus allowing for different styling from different sources. Do you have any recommendations for how I could go about changing my design?

Comment: Well if it is what I think it is; i.e. three totally different looks based on the type; that is fairly simple.   Basically your listview template has a different outputs based on the type.   I use this technique in my communicator app that I show how to build in my "Getting Started with NativeScript book" to make the chat window look different depending on who sends the content.   The idea basically is you tag each data item with a type; then you use that type to display the correct output template.